# iOS7 UIBackgroundModes Fetch with launch app from background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to download some files in the background with new iOS 7 feature `UIBackgroundModes Fetch` and file is downloading successfully in background

But I want`when my download completes in the background ,App should come in the Foreground`
I have also called the method `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
But `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler` method is not getting called in from background as well as foreground after download completes.

Is it possible to launch app in foreground after download completes?

Comment: Please check if Local Push notification works for you. There is a class UILocalNotification which is used to send notification from application. Please check if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can fire Local Notification for this purpose. Schedule local notification once your download completes. Once download finishes, App will fire notification, User selects the notification & after clicking it, the application will open up.

Here are some good tutorials for adding local notification:

[Local notification Sample 1](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/)

[Local notification sample 2](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/07/working-with-uilocalnotifications.html)

Comment: Thanks This works only when we tap on notification.is there any way to open directly without user touch

Comment: Without providing any interaction it might not be possible. Can you check if Calling your own application with URL Schema Works. I never tried it, but it is just a thought. It may be worth to give it a try.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it shows the correct way to bring an app to the foreground: through local notifications. It is pretty obvious why Apple has not provided a method without user intervention: what user would want a background app to suddenly pop up while they were using another app in the foreground?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, nope.

The only thing an app is supposed to do when called for a background fetch is perform any data fetching that the app needs. Then the completion handler is supposed to specify whether there was an error, new data, or no change. If there was new data, the app screenshot in the app switcher is updated. That's the extent of background fetching, hence the name.

There is no way to bring your app to the foreground. The only way to have an app come to the foreground in iOS is through a user action.

Comment: AnyThing similar to Remote Push notification when we tap on message opens the app